# rbenv version display in zsh right-prompt not refreshing

Tags: rvm, zsh, rbenv, zshrc

I have the following code in my .zshrc:

```
local ruby_version=''
if which rvm-prompt &> /dev/null; then
  ruby_version="$(rvm-prompt i v g)"
else
  if which rbenv &> /dev/null; then
    ruby_version="$(rbenv version | sed -e "s/ (set.*$//")"
  fi
fi
```

And I have this code in my RPS1 prompt:

```
RPS1='${PR_GREEN}$(virtualenv_info)%{$reset_color%} ${PR_RED}${ruby_version}%{$reset_color%}'
```

(For brevity sake I have not shown the code that sets the PR_ colors or determines the virtual environment - both of those work.)

When a new shell is created (new window or new tab in iTerm2) the Ruby information is correct. However if I switch to a project that uses a different Ruby, as determined by the `.ruby-version` file, the Ruby information displayed in the right prompt does not refresh. If I re-source my `.zshrc` file the right-prompt does refresh.

Do I need to encase the code that determines the Ruby version in a function? By the way, I do have `setopt promptsubst` in my .zshrc as well.

What am I missing that is preventing the right-prompt from refreshing when I change directories?

Comment: If I surround the `$(rbenv version | see -e "s/ (set.$//")` line with single quotes, then I see that string in my right-prompt. When that line is surrounded with double-quotes as shown in the original question, then I see the current Ruby only after sourcing `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be using this code

```
local ruby_version=''
if which rvm-prompt &> /dev/null; then
  ruby_version="$(rvm-prompt i v g)"
else
  if which rbenv &> /dev/null; then
    ruby_version="$(rbenv version | sed -e "s/ (set.*$//")"
  fi
fi
```

directly in zshrc: it won’t update ruby_version variable when switching to another project. You can change it to

```
function ruby_version()
{
    if which rvm-prompt &> /dev/null; then
      rvm-prompt i v g
    else
      if which rbenv &> /dev/null; then
        rbenv version | sed -e "s/ (set.*$//"
      fi
    fi
}
```

and change `${ruby_version}` in your prompt to `$(ruby_version)`. Or, if you are sure you don’t need checking this on each prompt (it will slow things down) you can use

```
function _update_ruby_version()
{
    typeset -g ruby_version=''
    if which rvm-prompt &> /dev/null; then
      ruby_version="$(rvm-prompt i v g)"
      rvm-prompt i v g
    else
      if which rbenv &> /dev/null; then
        ruby_version="$(rbenv version | sed -e "s/ (set.*$//")"
      fi
    fi
}
chpwd_functions+=(_update_ruby_version)
```

, it will update ruby_version only when you change current directory. Also note that your code is misleading: `local ruby_version=''` that is put directly into zshrc is equivalent to `typeset -g ruby_version=''` or just plain `ruby_version=''` which defines global, but not exported variable. There are no file-local variables in zsh (except for autoload files that actually represent functions).

Comment: Both of these variations worked perfectly. Thank you. I've implemented the second of the two, using the `chpwd_functions` line to only test the Ruby version when a directory changes. The only time this may be an issue is setting up a new project that has a local Ruby. After issuing the `rbenv local` command to define that Ruby, I'll have to leave the pwd and return to reset the prompt - a minor detail. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkNichols You don’t need to change directory two times. Just use `cd .`: it triggers `chpwd` hook, but does not actually change directory.

Comment: You don't need to run sed. rbenv has a command for version only. Just you rbenv version-name and you will get only the version you are looking for.

Comment: @Fa11enAngel I have no rbenv on my system and I know almost nothing about ruby development, just copied code from the question. Will not edit the post as OP may have had a reason for using `sed`: i.e. old versions of `rbenv` do not support `version-name`.

Answer (score 1):

use this one:

```
export ruby_version
if
  which rvm-prompt &> /dev/null
then
  ruby_version='$(rvm-prompt i v g)'
elif
  which rbenv &> /dev/null
then
  ruby_version='$(rbenv version | sed -e "s/ (set.*$//")'
else
  ruby_version=''
fi

RPS1='${PR_GREEN}$(virtualenv_info)%{$reset_color%} ${PR_RED}'"${ruby_version}"'%{$reset_color%}'
```

this will inject the `ruby_version` variable code into the `RPS1`

Comment: Using the above code my RPROMPT displays the text inside the single-quotes. Like so, `$(rbenv version | sed -e "s/ (set.*$//")`. Changing the single-quotes to double-quotes returns me to the original, incorrect, behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use the `precmd` hook which is executed every time you execute commands, like switching folders. Unlike the way you did it, that is only executed once when you start a new instance.

```
precmd () {

  local ruby_version=''
  if which rvm-prompt &> /dev/null; then
    ruby_version="$(rvm-prompt i v g)"
  else
    if which rbenv &> /dev/null; then
      ruby_version="$(rbenv version | sed -e "s/ (set.*$//")"
    fi
  fi

  #you can use RPROMPT
  RPS1='${PR_GREEN}$(virtualenv_info)%{$reset_color%} ${PR_RED}${ruby_version}%{$reset_color%}'
}
```

Make sure to not override this function, create it only if it wasn't created somewhere else. B Because it's very likely that it is already defined somewhere in your `.zshrc` or other zsh related files, especially if you are using something like *oh-my-zsh* or something else that shows git (or some other version control) information on the prompt or things like that.

[Some more light on the matter](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html).

Comment: I wrapped the RPROMPT with precmd after verifying that non of my zsh configuration has a precmd elsewhere. I was using on-my-zsh, but found it slow and therefore I'm rolling my own configuration now. There was no change in the behavior of the RPROMPT.  I'll have to continue reading the zsh manual.